# Site works in every browser but Opera and IE9 or earlier?

Tags: javascript, html, web, internet-explorer-9, opera

My site [www.globalplayernetwork.com](http://www.globalplayernetwork.com) works in Chrome, Firefox, and on IE 10 but not in IE 9 or earlier and Opera.

It seems the Nav bar and the logo are way too far down. What can I try to fix this?

HTML Page

**- Header**

```
  <section class="overlay">
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="http://www.globalplayernetwork.com/images/GPNLogo.png" height="165" width="590" alt="Global Player Network" title="Global Player Network" /> 
  </section>
```

**- Navigation Button**

```
  <nav> 
  <ul id="menu" class="menu"> 
  <li> 
  <a href="#" id="contact">
  <span class="active"></span> <span class="wrap"> 
  <span class="link">Contact</span> 
  <span class="descr">
  <font size="2"><b>Get in Touch</b></font></span>
  </span> 
  </a> 
  </li> 
  </ul> 
  </nav>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
ul.menu{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;font-size:14px;width:auto}
ul.menu a{text-decoration:none;outline:none}

ul.menu li{float:right;width:170px;height:85px;position:relative;cursor:pointer}

ul.menu li > a{position:absolute;top:-440px;right:0px;width:170px;height:78px;z-index:12;background:transparent url(../images/overlay.png) no-repeat bottom right;background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);-webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #000 inset;-moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #000 inset;box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #000 inset}

ul.menu li a img{border:none;position:absolute;width:0px;height:0px;bottom:0px;left:85px;z-index:100;-webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000;-moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000;box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000}

ul.menu li span.wrap{position:absolute;top:25px;left:0px;width:170px;height:60px;z-index:15}

ul.menu li span.active{position:absolute;background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);top:85px;width:170px;height:0px;left:0px;z-index:14;-webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000 inset;-moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000 inset;box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000 inset;-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:15px;-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:15px;border-bottom-right-radius:15px;-moz-border-radius-bottomright:15px;border-bottom-left-radius:15px;-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:15px}

ul.menu li span span.link,ul.menu li span span.descr,ul.menu li div.box a{margin-left:15px;text-transform:uppercase;font-size:33px;text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000}

ul.menu li span span.link{color:#fff;font-size:22px;float:left;clear:both}

ul.menu li span span.descr{color:#0B75AF;float:left;clear:both;width:155px;font-size:10px;letter-spacing:1px}

ul.menu li div.box{display:block;position:absolute;width:170px;overflow:hidden;height:170px;top:85px;left:0px;display:none;background:#000}ul.menu li div.box a{float:left;clear:both;line-height:30px;color:#0B75AF}

ul.menu li div.box a:first-child{margin-top:15px}ul.menu li div.box a:hover{color:#fff}

ul.menu{margin-top:150px}
```

Comment: post some code for the nav bar and logo

Comment: It looks like your website has some [HTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.globalplayernetwork.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) and [CSS](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.globalplayernetwork.com%2F&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en) errors. Try fixing those first and seeing what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is that you are not setting a HTML5 doctype but you are using HTML5 code, like

```
<nav> & <section>
```

etc.  These will be dropped by unsupported browsers.  if you must run HTML5 code then use a HTML5 shim for older versions of IE.

Also, on line 94 you have

```
</div>
```

also on line 1 you are missing

```
 <html>
```

and on line 74 you have

```
<span class="descr"><font size="2"><b>Pick Your Spot</span></b></font></span>
```

you can't start with a span, then font, then bold, and then reverse the order and end with span, then bold, then font...    you need to open and close your brackets properly

this is correct:

```
 <span class="descr"><font size="2"><b>Pick Your Spot</b></font></span>
```

line 82 you have a missing  tag

basically you are being forgiven by firefox but not by IE 9 which is less forgiving.

start by running your HTML through a validator and fix all the errors on missing tags.  Then your page navigation should correct itself.

check this link out:

[HTML Tidy](http://infohound.net/tidy/tidy.pl?_function=tidy&_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.globalplayernetwork.com%2F&_html=&_file=&x=28&y=18&alt-text=&clean=y&doctype=auto&drop-empty-paras=y&fix-backslash=y&fix-bad-comments=y&fix-uri=y&join-styles=y&lower-literals=y&ncr=y&new-blocklevel-tags=&new-empty-tags=&new-inline-tags=&new-pre-tags=&output-xhtml=y&quote-ampersand=y&quote-nbsp=y&indent=auto&indent-spaces=2&tab-size=4&wrap=90&wrap-asp=y&wrap-jste=y&wrap-php=y&wrap-sections=y&ascii-chars=y&char-encoding=ascii&input-encoding=latin1&output-bom=auto&output-encoding=ascii&_output=warn)

Comment: You forgot to mention that the font tag is depreciated in HTML4 and not supported in HTML5. CSS styles should be used instead.

Comment: Thank you, looks like I can also add something called a shiv for HTML5 for IE 7 and lower.

I will do my best fixing it up, thank you again!